# Android Camera Activity not giving save or discard option

Tags: android, camera

I tried some different camera activities and the best I found was this

https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil

But I haven't found any activity that fixes my problem. My problem is that when I debug with galaxy 3,5 and 6 everything works great.

When I debug with my Sony Xperia z5 compact the camera activity does not give me any option to Save or Discard the picture after picture is taken, it saves it right away.

I tried to google about this but I can not find anything about this
How can I set the code so it gives me a saving option after picture taken?

Comment: When you use implicit intents like that, the implementation is up to whatever app is selected to handle the intent.  There's no guarantee that the camera app that's being used will have an "accept" or "discard" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this works differently depending on a device. Some devices give the option to save and some just don't. Problem solved!